Is there a way to make a class with no limit on the number of Generic Type Parameters in c#?
I am working on a project in which I need to define any number of possible parameters when creating an object.
public class base
{
    //Variable Declarations here...
    
    public base(){ //Handle Arguments here... }
}

public class customCommand : base
{
    //Action Logic here...
}

My main issue comes from the declarations of "customCommand" (sorry for the poor naming conventions.) If the user wants to create an object that passes no further parameters, then the declaration works perfectly. However, If the user wants to create an object that does pass a parameter, I need to handle this with a new declaration.
The purpose of the script is to allow the user to create a command for a command-prompt-esc simulator. I have an 'interpreter' that will pass any parameters into the method that is associated with the command. My interpreter already "handles" type safety by returning whatever error the assigned function returns in a formatted way to the user. If the user needs to type "command1 [string] [int]" but they type "command1 [string] [string]", for example, the interpreter will see that the function assigned returned a type-error along with the type needed, and tell the user to try the command again with the correct syntax.
I would define command1 by creating an object like this:
private static customCommand<string,int> command1;
and I would define the method the command uses (for the interpreter) like this:
command1 = new customCommand<string,int>((x,y) =>
{
//some method
});

public class customCommand<T1> : base
{
    //New Action Logic here (handles T1)...
}

I understand one solution to this is simply limiting the user's ability to create an object with 'n' number of parameters, and writing out new definitions of new with <T1> * n parameters each, like:
public class customCommand<T1> : base { }
public class customCommand<T1,T2> : base { }
public class customCommand<T1,T2,T3> : base { } etc...

however, the possible inputs the user would have could exceed 10-11 entries, which would not only be a pain to manage in 10-11 different declarations but would also serve a messy solution.
I tried creating a class with an empty list of parameters. I expected to be able to create an object in which I could pass any number of parameters I needed.
public class customCommand<new T[]> { };

private static customCommand<string, string, int> test; //parameters are just an example

Any help would be appreciated, I am still learning. Thank you! (sorry for poor formatting, im trying to edit the post for the comments while running be

"Is there a way to make a class with no limit on the number of Generic Type Parameters" No. If you're making a method with, say, more than 3 generic arguments, you're probably going about things the wrong way. This is a good sign of a X/Y problem.

Nope, there is no such way. E.g. built in .NET Action delegate has 17 overloads

I need to define any number of possible parameters why? What's the actual problem that would solve? Why use even 3 types instead of just 1 with 3 properties? If the class is supposed to do something, why not use Action<> or Func<> ?

C# does have a params keyword which might work for you (I use it very rarely so little experience with it sorry). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/method-parameters#params-modifier By the same logic you could just pass an array to your constructor - or a context object.

@topsail params is only for method calls

The "why" matters. In functional language where eg tuples of different types are common, arbitrary types are handled by nesting tuples, not by having infinite parameters. Recursive functional code that handles 2 types can handle an infinite number because the second type can itself be a tuple. It's easy to write such code in C# and use tricks borrowed from functional languages like memoization to simplify the code and reduce or even eliminate the cost of recursion

@panagiotis-kanavos good point. I guess I never thought of merging the properties into one. Thank you for the suggestion.

I just used params in a constructor method :) No errors.

My suggestion was to explain the actual problem, not merging. Although, with record merging multiple values is now very easy.

@topsail that has nothing to do with this question at all. The question is about generic type parameters, not method parameters

okay no worries - I'll stay out of it now :) I probably just didn't read carefully I thought he just wanted to pass a variable number of arguments to a constructor.

@Panagiotis-Kanavos Oh. I suppose I read your response wrong. I want the user to be able to create an object with any number of parameters. Then, I want to take every parameter, and pass them into my interpreter script. I am making a modular command-prompt-esc program, and I want the user to be able to create their own commands that can be accessed, and understood by my interpreter. Hope this helps. Thanks!

@PanagiotisKanavos well, it may be part of the answer. As it seems OP uses generics for providing data to a class, which isn't really what generics are for.

Having said this: how would you use such an object. Imagine you could donew MyWeirdType(1, "hello", DateTume.Now). How would you use such an object, e.g. pass it to another function? Generally speaking generics are some way to say "an class of ...", like in "a List<Apple> is a list of apples". However a Warrior<Sword> wouldn`t fit this convention, as "a warrior of sword" is literal non-sense.

@MakePeaceGreatAgain the assumptions behind these comments are wrong. Functional languages already work this way and C# itself depends on this since LINQ. Action<> has up to 17 parameters for convenience but could easily handle more by using ValueTuple<> for more parameters. Use is relatively easy in C#: myAction((1,("banana",DateTime.Now())) but F# eliminates the need for explicit nesting. In C# 12, type aliasing can be used to give a nice name to any tuple

Exactly. The object is passed into my interpreter, which has the ability to use any number of parameters by looping through them. The issue I face is being able to define an object with as many parameters as the user wants. I think I will try to ask the user for one entry, that contains all of their wanted parameters, but merged.

@Zacc: You should try to change your question and provide better examples. These base and new1 classes are just confusing. People can't suggest you a good way if they don't understand what is it about. So don't hide it in your comments but edit your question. Imo i would simply pass an instance of InterpreterArguments to the Interpreter and process them there.

Why not just use a Dictionary<TKey, object> or simply a List<object> and iterate that in your interpreter? Of course you're losing type-safety. But you do anywhay while iterating, even with generics.

That was my exact thought. My interpreter already "handles" type safety by returning whatever error the assigned function returns in a formatted way to the user. If the user needs to type "command1 [string] [int]" but they type "command1 [string] [string]", for example, the interpreter will see that the function assigned returned a type-error along with the type needed, and tell the user to try the command again with the correct syntax.

But generics won't solve that at all, as these are a compile-time-thing. However your interpreter does all thiese checks at runtime. So just use a collection as mentioned above.

I think interfacing with an interpreter is a good use case for Reflection.  So just use object[]

Note that generic types, tuples and anonymous types are not dynamic. They are nailed down at compile time. If your scenario is dynamic (e.g. depending on a variable user input), then use a Dictionary<K, V> or a List<KeyValuePair<Type, object>>, a List<MyParameterDescription> or simply a List<object>.

Imagine there was a way to define such a class:
class MyClass<T1, ..., Tn> { ... }

How would you ever use this class? Imagine you'd wanted to put it into a function. How would the functions signature looks like?
DoSomething(MyClass<hmmmm, what arguments do I need here? T1? T2? T38?> args) { ... }

But even if that would work, how would you use that object in the method? All you could potentially do is iterating all these values. However you have no clue about what all these types actually are, so what does T38 resolve to? And does args even have so many arguments? E.g. how would you write such a loop:
foreach((hmmm, which type do I need here? T1?, T30? Both?) m in args) 
{
    ... 
}

You're stuck on indicating every single object as object, in which case you completely lose all the type-safety you actually wanted.
foreach(object m in args) 
{
    ... 
}

Even the class itself cannot really use these arguments. I suppose you want to use these values as some data-storage:
class MyClass<T1, ..., Tn>
{
    public T1 FirstValue;
    public T2 SecondValiue;
    // how many properties do I actually have? 
}

However when dealing with any arbitrary number of type-arguments, how would the class itself know, "how many properties it needs to create"?
So after all generics - which give you compile-time-types aren't the correct thing when you want to interpret the types at runtime.
What you can do instead is just baking all these values into a collection, e.g. a List<object> anf iterate that in your interepreter:
class MyClass 
{
    public object[] Values { get; }
    public MyClass(params object[] args) { this.Values = args; }
}

Now you can provide any arbitrary number of args to the class:
var m = new MyClass("Hello", 2, new MyClass());

Your interepreter just needs to iterate the args-array:
foreach(var o in m.Values)
{
   ...
}


I see how a theoretical 'infinite' number of potential arguments would be problematic. I couldn't find any industry documentation that would support the idea that command lines have a limit to arguments, but looking back, I suppose it makes sense. Addressing the solution, while my interpreter does handle the types that the arguments pass in the same way any other interpreter could, I do thing handling the types of the objects before sending them to the interpreter would be helpful for errors/outputs. Like you said, I will put the args in a list and rework the interpreter. Thank you!


I want the user to be able to create an object with any number of parameters. Then, I want to take every parameter, and pass them into my interpreter script. I am making a modular command-prompt-esc program, and I want the user to be able to create their own commands that can be accessed, and understood by my interpreter.

I would suggest thinking instead of a single argument that might represent multiple values; options that leap to mind:
// dictionary
var val = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    { "Id", 42 },
    { "Name", "abc" },
};
SomeMethod(val);

// anonymous type, using reflection magic in your library
var val = new { Id = 42, Name = "abc" };
SomeMethod(val);

// named value-tuple; note names aren't available via reflection,
// but are via "analyzers"
var val = (id: 42, name: "abc");
SomeMethod(val);

// unnamed value-tuple
var val = (42, "abc");
SomeMethod(val);

// POCO type, using reflection magic in your library
var val = new SomeType { Id = 42, Name = "abc" };
SomeMethod(val);

and those are just where your library does the tearing apart; another approach is to have some pair of types - for example IParameterHandler<T> i.e. for arg type Foo you might request an IParameterHandler<Foo> that the caller provides, which does this in the caller's code, extracting some number of typed arguments.
